# TwinCAT How to get file size

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation, filesize, twincat

I'm Trying to get file size I want to read (I want use dynamic allocation because I dont know how long CSV would be - so I have to know how many bytes I need).
I tried to use *FB_Tell* (with FB_OPEN with *MODEAPPEND* attribute) but I get 0. I thought that cursor in append mode will be set at the end of file and I get the size. Documentation said that cursor will move after writing something and append gets 0.
I tried to find something in BeckhoffInformationSystem, but there is no filesize functionblock or function.
Is there any option to do this? Maybe I should get some information using ADS and communicate with WindowsCE system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `FB_EnumFindFileEntry` [Infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/34982539.html?id=5692657966202396328)

Given a proper path, it will return a structure of type `ST_FindFileEntry` ([Infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35363851.html?id=2306276416492527815)) that contains, among other information, the file size in bytes

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found description of this structure and has more info about file, not only size [HERE in Beckhoff Information System](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35363851.html&id=)
Why they can't make good documentation and better search engine :(

Comment: A usefull trick to use google instead of infosys search - type the following in google `file size site:infosys.beckhoff.com`